# Apple Certificate, Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, react-native

I am newbie in mobile develop

so, I am very confusing for many things when upload app in apple store like :

certificate, provisioning profile, certificate signing request, identifier, ...

can anyone help me the easiest way to understand it.

i did read the document in internet, but still dont understand.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-code-signing-provisioning-in-a-nutshell-d5b247760bef#:~:text=Signing%20your%20app%20allows%20iOS,that%20Apple%20creates%20for%20you.&text=The%20Certificate%20will%20contain%20the,be%20downloaded%20to%20your%20system.) explained it quite well.

Comment: @Tj3n its a very nice explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to keep the desc. simple so you can understand easily...

**Certificate:**

The development certificate is used to develop apps internally, which are deployed on internal devices. However, distribution certificates are used to release apps to the App Store that can run on any device. iOS development certificates are usually associated with private keys.

**Provisioning Profile**

It is used to run app on the device or you can publish app using production provisioning profile. Without profile you can not run app on device, can not publish the app the App Store.

**Certificate signing request(CSR)**

This is the very first step in code signing iOS apps. You need to create a Certificate signing request (CSR) from their local machine, with some basic details confirming the developer's identity. The CSR needs to be sent to the Certificate Authority (CA), which is Apple for the iOS platform. Apple then confirms the developer's identity and issues a certificate to the developer. Anyone can create a CSR from their local macOS machine using the Keychain.

**Identifier**

This is the bundle identifier of your project. It must be unique among the apps already published to app store. You can enable capabilities to your identifier and regenerate the profiles in order to get that work.

More detail you can find [here](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-code-sign-publish-ios-apps/)

Comment: Thanks so much. i love this link